# Unbiasedness properties of Ratio/Proportion-type estimator

Tags: estimators, unbiased-estimator, ratio

I have a ratio estimator, $\hat{a} = n_1/(n_0+n_1)$, where $n_x$ refers to the frequency of $x$-valued data. Note that, $E(n_0)$ and $E(n_1)$ exists and strictly positive.

Usually, to show an estimator is unbiased, we need to show that $E(\hat{a}) = a$.
However, it can be shown if we do as below
$$
E(\hat{a}) = E(\frac{(n_1)}{(n_0 + n_1)}) = \frac{E(n_1)}{E(n_0) + E(n_1)} = a.
$$

However, opting to do as above must have solid reasoning/approximation/assumption. This method is very much wrong and I understand it. Unfortunately, I did not know where to find some ideas to do it. I have read some notes, some says about Slutsky Theorem, some say about approximation, some say about independence. Can anyone direct me to the path to show the estimator is biased or unbiased? Or links regarding this matter?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The equation you are providing needs the independence of the variables, right? So you want something more general?

Comment: @DamianoImola we can say $n_0$ and $n_1$ are independent because practically, the frequency of event not happening and happening only once can be considered as independent. But the ratio threw me off. If $n_0$ and $n_1$ are independent, will $n_0$ and $\frac{1}{n_0 + n_1}$ be independent as well?

Comment: Ok, I understood the problem. Surely $n_0$ and $\frac{1}{n_0+n_1}$ are not independents. That's because the ratio has to the denominator both $n_0$ and $n_1$, so the sum can't be independent from both of them. I just searched about ratio estimators on Wiki, and it tells that these are biased. In particular: *Ratio estimates are biased and corrections must be made when they are used in experimental or survey work* [Radio estimator-WIki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_estimator#:~:text=Ratio%20estimates%20are%20biased%20and,used%20to%20generate%20confidence%20intervals.). Hope this helps

Comment: Independence of numerator and denominator does not seem to be enough. By Jensen's inequality, if, say, $E(X)=\mu$ we have $E(1/X)\neq1/\mu$, as $E(1/X)\neq1/E(X)$.

Comment: @DamianoImola it helps so now I have to figure out how to make it bias-corrected and ultimately show that the ratio estimator is asymptotically unbiased.

Comment: @ChristophHanck is it possible to do like the following? $E(n_0/(n_0+n_1)) \geq E(n_0)/(E(n_0)+E(n_1))$?